# Updating a data.frame when clicked in DT

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

My `data.frame` has one logical column. I want to display the data with `DT::renderDataTable`, and I would like to toogle the value in the logical column when a row has been clicked.

I found a [working example](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-app-matrix-checkbox/108251/3) but I try to use `reactive` instead of `reactiveValues/observeEvent`.

Now the DT is shown and is doing some processing when clicked on a row, however, the values do not change. Here is the example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("myTable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    tableData = reactive({
        ans <-  data.frame(
            Name = LETTERS[1:6], 
            YesNo= rep(c(TRUE,FALSE), each=3),
            stringsAsFactors=FALSE
        )
        
        # transform T/F to checkbox symbol / NA 
        ans$YesNo <- ifelse(ans$YesNo, 
            as.character(shiny::icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon")), NA
        )
        
        # handle click on row
        if(!is.null(input$myTable_rows_selected)) {
            r_idx <- input$myTable_rows_selected[1]
            message("r_idx: ", r_idx)
            ans[r_idx, "YesNo"] <- ifelse(is.na(ans[r_idx, "YesNo"]),
                as.character(shiny::icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon")), NA
            )
        
            #Send proxy (no need to refresh whole table)
            DT::replaceData(DT::dataTableProxy('myTable'), ans)
        }
        ans
    })
 
    output$myTable = DT::renderDataTable({tableData()}, 
        selection = list(mode = "single", target = 'row'), 
        style = "bootstrap",
        rownames = FALSE, 
        colnames = c("Letter", "Yes?"),
        options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 25, 50, 100), pageLength = 5),
        escape=FALSE # do not show html code
    )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am stuck. Any hint appreciated.

Comment: I don't think `reactive` is a good approach for this problem. 1. The use of reactive is to store some data and can be used in other places, like you did `tableData`. However, you have a `replaceData` inside `reactive`, this is not recommended. You'd better do it inside observer not reactive. 2. The key thing of this problem is you need to have a container to store current state of the df and keep updating it on click, so inside the reactive, you can't use `ans`, it's the starting state not current state. You need to use `tableData`.

Comment: This creates a paradox, you can't call reactive itself inside itself. 
3. Another problem, for your `renderDataTable`, you don't want to call `tableData`, only call `ans`. Because you only render it one time with its initial state, later updates will use `replacedata`. 
`reactiveVal` and `reactiveValues` are the best solution I can think of here, another possible solution is to assign your df to global to update it (<<-), but this is not recommended shiny code style.

Comment: Thanks for these helpful explanations, @lz100. If you convert them to answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to repeat myself, so I just leave the comments there. Here is another approach with the global assignment `<<-`. So you don't need to use `reactiveValues` or `reactive` or `reactiveVal`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("myTable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    ans <<-  data.frame(
        Name = LETTERS[1:6], 
        YesNo= rep(c(TRUE,FALSE), each=3),
        stringsAsFactors=FALSE
    )
    ans$YesNo <<- ifelse(ans$YesNo, 
                        as.character(shiny::icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon")), NA
    )
    proxy <- dataTableProxy('myTable')
    
    observeEvent(input$myTable_rows_selected, {
        req(input$myTable_rows_selected)
        r_idx <- input$myTable_rows_selected[1]
        ans$YesNo[r_idx] <<- ifelse(is.na(ans$YesNo[r_idx]), as.character(shiny::icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon")), NA)
        DT::replaceData(dataTableProxy('myTable'), data = ans)
    })
    output$myTable = DT::renderDataTable({ans}, 
                                         selection = list(mode = "single", target = 'row'),
                                         style = "bootstrap",
                                         # rownames = FALSE,
                                         colnames = c("Letter", "Yes?"),
                                         options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 25, 50, 100), pageLength = 5),
                                         escape=FALSE # do not show html code
    )
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I commented out `rownames = FALSE`. If this is included, the update will not work. I don't know why, feels like a bug from DT.